# Privileges Necessary for Prepared Statement Execute Batch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small section of code using the PreparedStatement .addBatch() and .executeBatch() methods.

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
blah blah blah
```

I can execute most SQL statements fine, but not the batch operations. Do I need a specific privilege granted to my database user to use these operations?

**Edit**

If I need a particular privilege other than INSERT/UPDATE, which privilege do I need?

**Edit 2**

Turns out that my DBA didn't want to give my account the permissions it needed. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Yes you need to have permission to do this @jason

Comment: `ORA-nnnnn` errors are from the database, which doesn't know anything about JDBC or prepared statements. What is the statement trying to call in the database?

Comment: I understand that. I need to know what privilege I need granted to my database user (not application user) in order for PreparedStatement.executeBatch() to work.

Comment: To insert rows, you need the `INSERT` privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% but i think you don't need any special privileges to execute batch operation.
Probably your db user already has received the role `CONNECTION` or at least "CREATE SESSION" privilege.
You can do following thing

```
grant all on your_table to your_user;
```

where `all` means  `DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, TRIGGER, UPDATE`.
or select only relevant privileges.

```
grant  DELETE, INSERT, SELECT,  UPDATE on your_table to your_user.
```

if you are using sequence in your in you query. You have to also grant.

```
GRANT USAGE ON your_sequence to your_user
```

if you are using any custom package or function in your in you query. You have to also grant.

```
GRANT execute ON your_package to your_user
```